# Notification Service stops updating notifications after sometime if app is in background

Tags: android, notifications, background-service

I am trying to create a generic downloader in android and shows notification to user showing download progress. I also implemented background downloading which download files even after the app is killed.

For showing notifications I am using a Service (started using startService() method) and I am stopping the service after the download finishes.

The problem I am facing here is if I download something in background then notification service stops working after sometime.

The background thread which downloads the file keeps running but the notification service stops working.

In the logs I can that the NotificationListenerService which post notification in the status bar stop posting notifications for my app.

Here are some of the error log that I am getting

**11-24 18:49:29.987 3974-27955/? W/NotificationListenerService[]: onNotificationPosted: Error receiving StatusBarNotification**

**android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died**

Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT : FIND BELOW THE CODE WHERE THE SERVICE IS STARTED AND THE SERVICE WHICH HANDLES THE NOTIFICATION**

Here I start the notification service:

`if(!context.isDownloadNotificationServiceRunning()) {
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,DownloadNotificationService.class);                          notificationIntent.setAction(DownloadNotificationService.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_READY);                   context.startService(notificationIntent);
}`

Comment: are you using intentService or normal service

Comment: @jiteshmohite intent service

Comment: can you show your code I need see where and how you are creating object

Comment: updated my code

Comment: is your service not starting or notification is not updating

Comment: notification not updating..service start fine and notifications are also working fine for first few minutes but after sometime, service keeps running but notifications dont update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129000/discussion-between-jitesh-mohite-and-ezio).

Comment: IntenetService stops when onHandleIntent finishes. You might wanna use Service for that and then use background thread for downloading task. Also you may want to use foreground service.

Comment: Is it possible that android kills my notification service after a certain time.